# Prove density function of $Z=\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y$ is $\lambda f_X(z)+(1-\lambda)f_Y(z)$ where $\lambda\in(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If density functions of $X,Y$ are $f_X,f_Y$ then prove that density function of $Z=\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y$ is $\lambda f_X(z)+(1-\lambda)f_Y(z)$  where $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and $X,Y$ independent.

First of all we can think $Z=\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y$ as $Z$ takes the value $X$ with probability $\lambda$ and $Y$ with probability $(1-\lambda)$. Then i was thinking may be we can say $$f_Z(z)=f_{X\mid Z}(z\mid Z=X)f_Z(Z=X)+f_{Y\mid Z}(z\mid Z=Y)f_Z(Z=Y)$$this kind of stuff. But i am not sure that this is in fact correct.

Please tell me how to do this

Comment: I'm not sure your stated claim is true. Is $Z$ supposed to be instead $UX+(1-U)Y$ for some independent $\text{Bernoulli}(\lambda)$ random variable? This would match your "takes value $X$ with probability $\lambda$..." interpretation.

Comment: Yes you can think that

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the problem you are actually trying to solve is not the same as what is stated in your post. I will address the intended question (as stated in my comment).

We have $Z = UX + (1-U)Y$ where $U \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\lambda)$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$.

The CDF is

$$P(Z \le z) = P(U=1)P(Z \le z \mid U=1) + P(U=0) P(Z \le z \mid U=1)
= \lambda P(X \le z) + (1-\lambda) P(Y \le z).$$

Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $z$ yields the desired result regarding the densities.

Comment: we are not given that the density functions will be continuous. So cant differentiate right ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have densities (as your problem assumes), then their CDFs are differentiable and the derivative is the density (PDF). @SohamChatterjee