# Is $\lambda X + (1-\lambda) Y$ of density $\lambda f_X + (1-\lambda) f_Y$?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, combinations, density-function, random

Let $X,Y$ two random variable of density $f_X$ and $f_Y$. I was wondering under which condition (independence,...) the following statement is true. For $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ is $\lambda X + (1-\lambda) Y$ of density $\lambda f_X + (1-\lambda) f_Y$ ?
Normality is a first answer ! But is it true in other contexts ?

I can't find any specifics about this question, since it's not exactly a mixture distribution. The following link
[Prove density function of $Z=\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y$ is $\lambda f_X(z)+(1-\lambda)f_Y(z)$ where $\lambda\in(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446873/prove-density-function-of-z-lambda-x1-lambday-is-lambda-f-xz1-lamb) is pointing the confusion, but no clear answer.

Thank your for your help

Comment: This happens very rarely. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent with mean $0$ and finite variance this cannot happen unless $X$ and $Y$ are both $0$. (I can post a proof if you are interested).

Comment: @geetha290krm Is there a problem in the computations of $E[(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y)^2]$

Comment: Yes, computing it gives  a contradiction in the case I mentioned

Comment: Yes thank you I got it !

Comment: There is one case though where this does happen. If $X$ an $Y$ are i.i.d. with Cauchy distribution then the  density of $\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y$ is $\lambda f_X+(1-\lambda ) f_Y$.